# User routing in ASP.NET MVC for urls like www.website.com/users/jeffAtwood

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to show user details at the following url :

www.website.com/users/yasser

where the last entry `yasser` is the username I have tried a couple of routes but it just does nt work.

My User controller is as shown below.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        var model = _service.GetUserDetails(username);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I have reffered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000547/asp-net-mvc-user-routing-like-that-in-stackoverflow) and couple of other links, but I really could not figure out how it worked.

Can some one help me out on this. Thanks

**Edit** :

My current route config is below

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Given the fact that your controller is "UserController" the link will be www.website.com/user/yasser; unless you specified another route in global.asax. Also this way of accessing the users details must assume that the username is unique

Comment: but it does not work, I have updated the question with my route details, and no I dont have any other route specified. when i type in www.website.com/user/yasser I get `Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.` 404 message. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Routes executes from top to the bottom:

```
routes.MapRoute("UserProfile",
     "Users/{username}",
     new { controller = "User", action = "Index", username = string.Empty }
);

routes.MapRoute("Default",
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Comment: yes ! I had forgotten about the routing getting executed from top to bottom, and I was placing my routes below the default route because of which it was not working. Thanks @webdeveloper.