# ASP.net MVC4 Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

any tips on how i can make user URLs

for example   http://www.example.com/username

will display a dynamic page containing the user’s profile on ASP.net MVC4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get your job done,

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "UserProfile",
            "{username}",
            new { controller = "User", action = "Index", username = string.Empty }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

public class UserController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Speaking of user profile page, I think you should take some time and update your profile details on Stackoverflow ;)

Welcome to Stackoverflow !

**Further Reading:**

- [User routing in ASP.NET MVC for urls like www.website.com/users/jeffAtwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207043/user-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-for-urls-like-www-website-com-users-jeffatwood)
- [ASP.NET MVC User routing like that in StackOverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000547/asp-net-mvc-user-routing-like-that-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: Hi there. I have already did this one. I used [link](http://itcloudwebrouting.codeplex.com/)'s routing assembly. Thanks for the answer though. (and for welcoming. :) )